# Unit testing custom validator

Tags: symfony, phpunit

My validator looks like:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Infrastructure\Domain\Model\Company\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

final class ContainsUnsupportedSymbolsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function __construct(
        private TranslatorInterface $translator
    )
    {
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof ContainsUnsupportedSymbols) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, ContainsUnsupportedSymbols::class);
        }

        // custom constraints should ignore null and empty values to allow
        // other constraints (NotBlank, NotNull, etc.) to take care of that
        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            // throw this exception if your validator cannot handle the passed type so that it can be marked as invalid
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($value, 'string');
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^\+?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{6,12}$/', $value, $matches)) {
            // the argument must be a string or an object implementing __toString()
            $this->context->buildViolation(
                $this->translator->trans($constraint->message, ['{phone}' => $value])
            )->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

The test I wrote for valid case is:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Unit\Infrastructure\Domain\Model\Company\Validator;

use App\Infrastructure\Domain\Model\Company\Validator\ContainsUnsupportedSymbols;
use App\Infrastructure\Domain\Model\Company\Validator\ContainsUnsupportedSymbolsValidator;
use App\Tests\Unit\UnitTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

final class ContainsUnsupportedSymbolsValidatorTest extends UnitTestCase
{
    public function testValidatorWithValidPhone():void
    {
        $phone = "+359883202020";

        $translationMock = $this->createMock(TranslatorInterface::class);

        $constraint = new ContainsUnsupportedSymbols();

        $constraintValidator = new ContainsUnsupportedSymbolsValidator($translationMock);

        $this->assertEmpty($constraintValidator->validate($phone, $constraint));
    }
}
```

Is it correct to test with `assertEmpty` when the `validate` method return type is `void`?
And how to test with incorrect data? Tried to mock the `context` and both `buildViolation` and `addViolation` methods but got error:

> Error: Call to a member function buildViolation() on null

This is what I tried with incorrect phone

```
public function testValidatorWithInvalidPhone():void
    {
        $phone = "+359()883202020";

        $translationMock = $this->createMock(TranslatorInterface::class);

        $contextMock = $this->createMock(ExecutionContextInterface::class);
        $contextMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('buildViolation')
            ->with('message');
        $contextMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('addViolation');

        $constraint = new ContainsUnsupportedSymbols();

        $constraintValidator = new ContainsUnsupportedSymbolsValidator($translationMock);

        $this->assertEmpty($constraintValidator->validate($phone, $constraint));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your context is null. You have to initialize the `ConstraintValidator` extended by your custom validator.
The question has found an answer here: [Unit testing a custom symfony constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473271/unit-testing-a-custom-symfony-constraint)

In short here is an example https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Tests/Constraints/BlankValidatorTest.php

In the example the test class extends `ConstraintValidatorTestCase` that defines a context (look here: https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/6.1/Test/ConstraintValidatorTestCase.php)

Comment: Yours answer is correct if you're having a validator without constructor. While I was searching for a solution of my problem (having ConstraintValidator with constructor in which I'm using a repository). Unfortunately I'm still looking for an answer...